# docker-compose pull Error: "error creating temporary lease: read-only file system"

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run `docker-compose pull` but I get some errors that I don't know what to do with.

My `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  strapi:
    image: strapi/strapi
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: postgres
      DATABASE_NAME: strapi
      DATABASE_HOST: postgres
      DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      DATABASE_USERNAME: strapi
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: strapi
    volumes:
      - ./app:/srv/app
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: strapi
      POSTGRES_USER: strapi
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: strapi
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

The error message:

```
Pulling postgres ... error
Pulling strapi   ... error

ERROR: for strapi  error creating temporary lease: write /var/lib/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt/meta.db: read-only file system: unknown

ERROR: for postgres  error creating temporary lease: write /var/lib/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt/meta.db: read-only file system: unknown
ERROR: error creating temporary lease: write /var/lib/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt/meta.db: read-only file system: unknown
error creating temporary lease: write /var/lib/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt/meta.db: read-only file system: unknown
```

Comment: Can you try to restart the docker `systemctl restart docker`?

Answer (score 2):

I tried a multitude of things so YMMV, but here are all of the steps I did that ultimately got it working.

**I am using Windows 10 with WSL2 backend on Ubuntu**, so again YMMV as I see MacOS is tagged. This is one of the few questions I see related to mine, so I thought it would be valuable.

### Steps for success:

- Update WSL (`wsl --update` -- unrelated to the GitHub issue below)
- stop Docker Desktop
- stop WSL (`wsl --shutdown`)
- unregister the docker-desktop distro (which contains binaries, but no data)

  - `wsl --unregister docker-desktop`
- restart Docker Desktop (try running as admin)
- Enable use of docker compose V2 (`settings` -> `general` -> `Use Docker Compose V2`)

[Associated GitHub issue link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/8308#issuecomment-685605868)

### Extra Info:

I ended up using V2 of docker compose when it worked... it works either way now that the image has pulled properly, though.

I unsuccessfully restarted, reinstalled, and factory reset Docker Desktop many times.